# Извлечь адрес float переменной из памяти процесса (C# или C++)

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю небольшую простую программу на WinForms C# с импортом нескольких методов WinAPI, которая должна манипулировать окном mmorpg-игры.

В клиенте mmorpg-игры есть параметр здоровье, оно точно хранится в переменной типа float. (Было проверено с помощью утилиты cheat engine)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие методы здесь проще всего применить, чтобы при каждом новом запуске клиента точно знать где в памяти хранится это значение.

Upd: Не ясно какое из них передаётся в функцию, а какое отвечает непосредственно, однако, изменять их не нужно. Как проще всего найти этот float в памяти с каждым запуском? (Используя средства .Net и импортирование WinAPI)

[image: target game window]

Comment: вообще говоря, без помощи пользователя никак. Процесс может быть загружен в произвольную область памяти по выбору ОС, искомый объект может быть создан в относительно произвольной области памяти принадлежащей процессу по выбору алгоритмов процесса. Как вы представляете себе поиск абстрактного числа в памяти, которая по сути, только числа и хранит? Даже при сканировании на совпадение с некоторой точностью, потребуется 2+ проходов с указанием новых значений поиска на каждом проходе для отсева не изменившихся из предыдущих найденных.

Comment: Даже у вас на картинке целых 4 значения, какое из них отвечает за ваш параметр непосредственно а не является копией которую передали в функцию или значением локальной переменной функции?

Comment: Используйте не абсолютный адрес, а относительный. Например, адрес относительно начала программы.